# only allow a specific port that can be connected by only one ip address at the same time

Tags: iptables, port, ips, connlimit

I have a open port, 40002,  I want to limit that at the same time the port can only be connected by one ip address(not specific address).  if there is an ip address conntecing to that port already, other IPs will fail to connect.

is is possible to configure it by Iptables or scripts? my system is Ubuntu 14.04 
thanks.

Comment: only allow  one ip(not specific ) through specific port at the same time?

Comment: This may not be a good idea. If you are under DDoS attack (multiple machine trying to half-open a connection on this specific port), you won't be able to initiate a legitime connection.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by configuring iptables.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport $port -m connlimit --connlimit-above N -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
# save the changes see iptables-save man page, the following is redhat and friends specific command
service iptables save
```

## Example : Limit SSH Connections Per IP / Host

```
/sbin/iptables  -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 3 -j REJECT
# save the changes see iptables-save man page, the following is redhat and friends specific command
service iptables save
```

TESTING :

```
#!/bin/bash
ip="202.1.2.3"
port="80"
for i in {1..100}
 do
 # do nothing just connect and exit
echo "exit" | nc ${ip} ${port};
done
```

## OK : To limit n connections max here is an example using the ip limit module :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -dport 40002 -m iplimit --iplimit-above 3 -J REJECT
```

This will REJECT connections if there are 3 IPs connected. Sorry if I misunderstood your question ;)

Comment: Hi LScarpinati, thanks for your information. however, I think you may misunderstand my question.  the command you provide can really limit 3 session for same IP.  but conversely I want to limit that can only 3 IP to connect, the fourth IP will fail to connect  if there are 3 IPs connecting.  in a word, I want to limit IP numbers, not sessions . sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my answer. I let the other example for info. ; )